# I can't access variable from foreach loop out side of condition

Tags: python

I am trying to read multiple files at a time. My code working fine when i try to print the values inside if condition. But when i try to print values out the if condition it show invalid variable name.

I want to access`Contentdata` and `description` data. but don't know how can i access them and i have to store them in my firebase database

```
for i,j,y in os.walk(bookpath):
    name = i
    book = {
        'name': name,
    }
    foldername = name.replace('MHE/2013/', '')
    content = name+"/content.txt"
    description = name+"/description.txt"
    imagepath = name+"/"+foldername+".jpg"
    for file in y:
        if path.exists(content):
            if file == "content.txt":
                rawdata = open(content, 'rb').read()
                result = chardet.detect(rawdata)
                charenc = result['encoding']
                with open(content, encoding=charenc) as cont:
                    contentdata = cont.read()
        if path.exists(description):
            if file == "description.txt":
                rawdata = open(description, 'rb').read()
                result = chardet.detect(rawdata)
                charenc = result['encoding']
                with open(description, encoding=charenc) as desc:
                    descriptiondata = desc.read()
        if path.exists(imagepath):
            if file == foldername+".jpg":
                imageBlob = bucket.blob("images/"+os.path.basename(imagepath))
                imageBlob.upload_from_filename(filename=imagepath)
                imagename = "images/"+foldername+".jpg" //this works fines
        else:
            imagename = "null"
```

Comment: Please provide a little more information such as the stack trace, what variable name is invalid, etc.

Comment: @Ashish Please provide a MCVE. Nothing appears wrong in your code and you haven't given us an error. (other than misplacing some syntax. `// This is not a comment in Python`, `# This is.`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if path.exists(content):
    if file == "content.txt":
        rawdata = open(content, 'rb').read()
        result = chardet.detect(rawdata)
        charenc = result['encoding']
        with open(content, encoding=charenc) as cont:
            contentdata = cont.read()
```

If the `content` path does not exist, or `file` is not equal to "content.txt", 
`contentdata` is never created.

In this case, what do you want `contentdata` to be?  Should it be null, or a blank string, or some default message such as "Content not found"?

If you want `contentdata` to always have a value, you should initialize it at the top of the code, in the same place where you initialize `foldername` and `content`.

Answer (score 0):

`contentdata` and `descriptiondata` are assigned inside `if` blocks, which may not execute.  If they don't execute, those variables will not be assigned, and you'll get a `NameError` when you try to reference them.

You need to figure out what you want to happen if those `if` blocks don't execute, and respond appropriately.